# Adding strings to ArrayList but still seeing size 0

Tags: java, android

```
public class Thirdfragment extends Fragment {

    List names = new ArrayList();


    public Thirdfragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("serviceop");    
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    if (objects.size() > 0) {    
                        for (ParseObject object : objects) {    
                            String Currentdatatype = object.getString("name");

                       names.add("s");    
                       Log.d("added",Currentdatatype);    
                        }
                    } else {    
                        Log.d("no data","left or right");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("awserror","left or right");
                }
            }
        });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        System.out.println("Using for loop");
        System.out.println("--------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(names.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println(names.size());
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"ssd","sd"});
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

I need a little hand here, please, because I keep on trying to add strings to my list, but the size of the names is still showing me 0. I don't know why this happens. In the logcat i don't see any values, it is still showing me the 0 value. I cannot post the log here because Stack Overflow is not accepting my question and is showing some errors.

Comment: Why the downvotes, please? The code example isn’t exaclty [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but complete and verifiable, and the question is clear. Not bad for a new Stack Overflow user. Please be nice and leave a helpful comment on how this and future posts can be improved.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use raw types, as that one answer suggests!

Answer (score 4):

*findInBackground* method is asynchronous (is executed in a background thread). The FindCallback that you pass to this method will be executed eventually **after** the query is executed.

You are iterating through your list **before** any values are actually added. This is your problem.

Either use find() method to fetch ParseObjects (but keep in mind that this is a blocking operation), or move your iteration logic to FindCallback.

Hope this helps.

Comment: will you help me with coding /clear tips because iam new to coding-irahavoi

Comment: @SubhashChandru, I edited my answer. Hopefully, it's clearer now. Happy coding :)

Comment: still, I don't get it.Can you please clear me the code that would be great for me, sir@irahavoi

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause:** You are using `query.findInBackground` to add data to your array list in a background thread, in the meantime you are accessing the array list value in the UI thread. Because 2 threads are running concurrency so in some cases the UI thread executes or runs before the background thread. That why your array list is empty.

**Solution:** Set adapter to `RecyclerView` when data is ready.

**ThirdFragment.java**

```
public class Thirdfragment extends Fragment {

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    public Thirdfragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("serviceop");

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (objects.size() > 0) {
                        for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                            String Currentdatatype = object.getString("name");
                            names.add("s");
                            Log.d("added", Currentdatatype);
                        }

                        // The data (names array list) is already to use.
                        String[] namesArray = new String[names.size()];
                        namesArray = names.toArray(namesArray);
                        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(namesArray);
                        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("no data", "left or right");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("awserror", "left or right");
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SubhashChandru see my updated answer, your data (names array list) is ready when the background thread finish its execution. I add a comment line inside findInBackground method to indicate when the data is ready.

Comment: but i have some problems and i should not use my adapter inside that query process , is there any solution for that ?

Comment: Why not, if you do not use adapter inside, the UI thread must wait until the background thread finish its execution. But it might block the UI thread and the app will crash. Or you can write a method that accept an array list a parameter and call it from background thread to update your adapter.